# Refresh remote Windows server user profile from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I'm working on a project where I need to refresh a particular user profile on a number of machines each night. It's helpful to leave evidence that the refresh has been done. Therefore my manual process is to rename the documents and settings folder and delete the user registry key.

I'm trying to script it from powershell from where I can rename the remote user folder but not being able to delete the registry key. What I have so far is trying to delete my local sid from the remote server.

Can I identify and delete the required remote sid?

```
[array] $Computers =  "computer2", "computer1", "computer3"
ForEach ($computer in $Computers) { 
#rename the folder
$source = "\\$computer\c$\Documents and Settings\theUser"
$dest = "\\$computer\c$\Documents and Settings\theUser.old"
Rename-Item -path $source -newname $dest -force
#delete the SID
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("theUser")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
REG DELETE "\\$computer\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$strSID"
}
```

Comment: Windows 2000? As in "no updates since 2010"? Seriously?

Comment: the OS is irrelevant to the question, I've removed the tag.